# Babel - Typescript preset

Tags: typescript, document, babeljs

I am trying to use babel's typescript preset following the instructions in their [docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-typescript).

I get some errors when I do this (`Unexpected token {` next to the import statement). I end up having to add the `@babel/preset-env` as well to fix this.

Things are working but my question is why is the need for the env preset not mentioned in the docs? or am I missing something?

Comment: Not specific to typescript, you would need it with plain js as well

Comment: So the typescript preset only handles transforming the type 'annotations' everything else must go through the regular pipeline, is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, you're right